# Variadic macro with empty argument in c++11

Tags: c++, c++11, macros

An old header of mine contains a variadic macro that allows for 0 arguments.  When compiled against C++11 with gcc 4.7.3 the `##` token no longer seems to remove the preceding comma.

```
#define FOOCRO(...) printf("42\n", ## __VA_ARGS__)

int main(){
    FOOCRO(); // dumped from gcc -E: printf("42\n",); //comma still in place
    return 0;
}
```

I thought it might be a spacing issue but placement of `##` doesn't seem to have any effect on comma removal.

**Edit**:

Lest I get dinged for some perceived mis-use of a hated feature, this is the source macro I simplified for this question:

```
#define LOG(...) Logger::Write(__FILE__,__LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__)
```

I've yet to come across a less "evil" way of doing debugging short of writing all that cruft every time I insert a debug statement.

Comment: Are you using `-std=c++11`?  That would disable GNU extensions like this.  Try with `-std=gnu++11` instead.

Comment: When they are porting old code and hoping to avoid unnecessary rewrites?

Comment: @ChrisDodd That did the trick, didn't realize it was an extension.  This code was only ever compiled in VS.

Comment: Have you thought about something like: `#define LOG(...) (Logger::Write(__FILE__,__LINE__)(__VA_ARGS__))`? You have `Logger::Write` return a function object and then you call it with the macro arguments.

Comment: @Simple Indeed.  That's pretty much how I'm approaching this problem.